# Partition in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with no possible refinement

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I was wondering, is it possible for a partion of a hyperrectangle $P \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e. a set of a form $P = [a_1, b_1] \times ... \times [a_n, b_n]$ to have no refinements?

If so, what is an example of such set?

Comment: All partition is refinement of itself. If this argument is not enough, then, a partition in a hyperrectangle is induced by a partition on evey interval $[a_i,b_i]$. Take a refinement of this interval and clearly is a refinement of the partition of the hyperrectangle.

Comment: What are the requirements for a partition to have a proper refinement? If you think about that, maybe you'll see the answer.